# How can I disable panning on left click in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3, pan works both in (left or right click) + drag.
However, in my case I want to reserve the (left click + drag) for other actions while (right click + drag) do the panning.

How can I disable panning on left click?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue as follows:

```
function doDrag() {
   if (d3.event.button === 0) {
       d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
  //other drag work
}
```

I call this function on mousedown event.

Answer (score 1):

Add check on mouse down in your function where you handle the drag.

```
function doDrag(){
   if(d3.event.sourceEvent.button == 0){
     d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return;
   }

   //other drag work
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. your post led me to actual solution:

function doDrag() {
    if (d3.event.button === 0) {
        d3.event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
        
    //other drag work
}

Comment: Thanks Updated my answer!